# get the offset of a tuple element

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, constexpr

I have wrote the following code to get the offset of a tuple element

```
template<size_t Idx,class T>
 constexpr size_t tuple_element_offset() {
        return static_cast<size_t>(
                    reinterpret_cast<char*>(&std::get<Idx>(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(0))) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(0));
    }
```

This is actually similar to the implementation of the **offsetof** macro.
It looks ugly, but compiles and works fine on gcc-4.6

```
typedef std::tuple<int,char,long> mytuple;

mytuple var = std::make_tuple(4,'c',1000);
char * ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&var);
long * pt = reinterpret_cast<long*>(ptr+tuple_element_offset<2,mytuple>());

std::cout << *pt << std::endl;
```

prints "1000".

I don't know too much about constexpr, so my questions are:

1. Is it legal c++?
2. More important, why I am allowed to call
   std::get (which is non constexpr)
   inside a constexpr function?

As far as I understand constexpr, the compiler is forced to evaluate the result
of the expression at compile time, so no zero-dereferentiation can occurs in practice.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @James: I have some tuples of fixed-sized vectors of float. I need the offset of each element to use the tuples with the OpenGL functions glVertexPointer,glColorPointer etc. Since the attributes of each vertex may vary a lot inside the project, I think that is better to use tuples instead of define my own vertex structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it legal C++?

If by "legal" you mean "well-formed," then, yes.

If by "legal" you mean "valid and will work on any compiler and Standard Library implementation, then, no, because `std::tuple` is not POD.

> Why I am allowed to call `std::get` (which is not `constexpr`) inside a `constexpr` function?

Basically, a `constexpr` function doesn't necessarily have to consist of just a constant expression.  If you tried to use your `tuple_element_offset()` function in a constant expression, you'd get a compilation error.

The idea is that a function might be usable in a constant expression in some circumstances but not in others, so there isn't a restriction that a `constexpr` function must always be usable in a constant expression (since there isn't such a restriction, it's also possible that a particular `constexpr` function might never be usable in a constant expression, as is the case with your function).

The C++0x draft has a good example (from 5.19/2):

```
constexpr const int* addr(const int& ir) { return &ir; } // OK

// OK: (const int*)&(const int&)x is an address contant expression
static const int x = 5;
constexpr const int* xp = addr(x); 

// Error, initializer for constexpr variable not a constant expression; 
// (const int*)&(const int&)5 is not a constant expression because it takes
// the address of a temporary
constexpr const int* tp = addr(5);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's well-formed? The second sentence of 18.1/5 is a "shall" rule, it doesn't mention undefined behavior, and it doesn't state that no diagnostic is required. So compilers are required to diagnose it. Since the program doesn't conform to diagnosable semantic rules, it's not well-formed. I think.

Comment: @Steve:  The OP's code doesn't use `offsetof`, there's a hand-rolled `offsetof`-like function.

Comment: @Steve: I also don't think that is intended to be a diagnosible semantic rule. I can't find explicit language that would make that rule "no diagnostic required," but really, the spirit of 17.4.3.8 and the subclauses that precede that would seem to apply. I don't believe any of the rules in the Library spec are intended to be diagnosible semantic rules. (Now that I've said that, someone is going to go find a rule, I know it...)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. 17.4.3.8 is about functions, and `offsetof` isn't a function, but since you're suggesting the *spirit* that's not really a counter. However, since the *third* sentence of 18.1/5 does specify undefined behavior, it seems to me likely that the contrast is deliberate, and that the second sentence *is* intended to be diagnosable. However, I confess I'm a bit puzzled why they should be different, since I'd think there's no difference in practical difficulty of diagnosing them. Both are deducible from the class definition, but not deducible by a dumb macro.

Comment: Actually, no, on second thoughts, the third sentence *can* be diagnosed by a dumb macro, in that the typical `&(((type*)0)->member)` thing just won't compile. The second sentence is *harder* to diagnose, so it would be nuts to require that it be diagnosed, but not require the same of the easier one. So you must be right, the intention must be that it's not diagnosable, but I suspect neither of us cares deeply whether there's language in the standard to say so, or if it's technically a defect. And you're right about the OP code not using `offsetof`, of course. Time to sleep, I think!